# What would cause clSetKernelArg to give CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT on a valid memory object?

Tags: c++, opencl

I am working on an opencl project in c++ to run a physics simulation on my graphics card. As the title says I get CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT as an error when I call clSetKernelArg. I know that the memory object is in fact valid, since I can query the object just before the call and I get no errors and the buffer size is correct. The other thing that I thought it might be was that I was creating the context and device objects in a different thread, which, while it is something that I should fix, I ruled out as the cause of this problem by getting rid of the extra thread. Everything seems to be valid at the time of the call and I have yet to find another explanation for this. Here is the relevant code...

Kernel wrapper class...

```
//This sets a kernel arg of basic types and runs without error
template <typename T>
    inline bool setKernelArg (uint32_t pos, const T* data)
    {
        int err = clSetKernelArg(m_kernel, pos, sizeof(T), data);
        LOG_ERROR_IF("Could not set kernel argument! " + std::to_string(err), err != CL_SUCCESS );
        return err != CL_SUCCESS;
    }
//This sets a kernel arg for memorybuffers and gives the error
    template<typename T>
    inline bool setKernelMemBufferArg (uint32_t pos, const MemBuffer<T>* data)
    {
        int err = clSetKernelArg (m_kernel, pos, sizeof (cl_mem), data->getMemBuffer());
        LOG_ERROR_IF ("Could not set kernel argument! " + std::to_string (err), err != CL_SUCCESS);
        return err != CL_SUCCESS;
    }
```

The getter for the mem buffer...

```
inline const cl_mem getMemBuffer() const {return m_memBuffer;}
```

And the Calling methods...

```
void NBodySim::init ()
{
        p_cmdq = std::make_shared<CommandQueue> (p_con.get (), p_device.get ());
        p_program = std::unique_ptr<Program> (Program::createProgram ("src/Compute/Kernels/PhysKernel.cl",
                                                                                                                                    *p_con, *p_device));
        p_kern = std::unique_ptr<Kernel> (Kernel::createKernel (p_program.get (), p_cmdq, "calcPos"));

        p_starMassBuffer = std::shared_ptr<MemBuffer<float>> (MemBuffer<float>::createMemBufferWithData (
            p_con, p_cmdq, m_numStars, m_starMassArr,
            BufferFlags::Read_Only | BufferFlags::Copy_Host_Ptr));

        p_starPosInBuffer = std::shared_ptr<MemBuffer<cl_float3>> (MemBuffer<cl_float3>::createMemBufferWithData (
            p_con, p_cmdq, m_numStars, m_starPosArr,
            BufferFlags::Read_Only | BufferFlags::Copy_Host_Ptr));

        p_starVelInBuffer = std::shared_ptr<MemBuffer<cl_float3>> (MemBuffer<cl_float3>::createMemBufferWithData (
            p_con, p_cmdq, m_numStars, m_starVelArr,
            BufferFlags::Read_Write | BufferFlags::Copy_Host_Ptr));
        p_starPosOutBuffer = std::shared_ptr<MemBuffer<cl_float3>> (MemBuffer<cl_float3>::createMemBuffer (
            p_con, p_cmdq, m_numStars,
            BufferFlags::Read_Write));
        p_starVelOutBuffer = std::shared_ptr<MemBuffer<cl_float3>> (MemBuffer<cl_float3>::createMemBuffer (
            p_con, p_cmdq, m_numStars,
            BufferFlags::Read_Write));
    
}
void NBodySim::run ()
{
    m_simThread = std::thread([=]() 
    {
        init();

        float softeningFactor = 100.0f;
        float timeStep = 75000 * 3.154e+07; // 75,000 years in seconds 
        std::shared_ptr<IO::StarFileMT> file (IO::StarFileMT::createFile (m_filePath, m_numStars, m_numTimesteps));
        size_t globalWorkSize = m_numStars;
        size_t localWorkSize = p_kern->getPreferredWorkGroupSize(p_device.get());
        for ( int i = 0; i < m_numTimesteps; i++ )
        {
            p_kern->setKernelMemBufferArg(0, p_starPosInBuffer.get());
            p_kern->setKernelMemBufferArg(1, p_starMassBuffer.get());
            p_kern->setKernelArg<float>(2, &softeningFactor);
            p_kern->setKernelArg<float>(3, &timeStep);
            p_kern->setKernelMemBufferArg(4, p_starVelInBuffer.get());
            p_kern->setKernelMemBufferArg(5, p_starPosOutBuffer.get());
            p_kern->setKernelMemBufferArg(6, p_starVelOutBuffer.get ());


            p_kern->runKernel(1, globalWorkSize, localWorkSize);

            std::vector<cl_float3> result = p_starPosOutBuffer->pullFromBuffer(m_numStars);
            file->writeTimeStep (Application::clFloatArrToVec3f (result.data(), m_numStars));
            p_starPosInBuffer->copyFromBuffer (p_starPosOutBuffer.get (), m_numStars);
            p_starVelInBuffer->copyFromBuffer(p_starVelOutBuffer.get(), m_numStars);

            incrementTimestepsDone();
        }
    }
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you passing the cl_mem object to clSetKernelArg instead of its address? Try `&data->getMemBuffer()`.

Comment: @Jan-Gerd This was a very good suggestion. This was part of the issue except the solution was a bit weirder since that gives me a "'&' requires l-value" error. So it involved me writing a method in the memBuffer class that returns a '''void**'''. That method method make me very nervous, but it is the workaround that I have found for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

As @jan-gerd mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68749715/what-would-cause-clsetkernelarg-to-give-cl-invalid-mem-object-on-a-valid-memory#comment121509323_68749715) above the problem is that the memory object is passed to `clSetKernelArg` instead of its address. But it is not necessary to write the function that returns `void**`, you can modify the getter

```cpp
inline const cl_mem& getMemBuffer() const {return m_memBuffer;}
```

and use it with `clSetKernelArg`

```cpp
int err = clSetKernelArg (m_kernel, pos, sizeof (cl_mem), &(data->getMemBuffer()));
```

or you can create additional getter for it, for example:

```cpp
inline const cl_mem getMemBuffer() const {return m_memBuffer;}
inline const cl_mem& getMemBufferRef() const {return m_memBuffer;}
```